# Displaying an image with Python Matlibplot and im.show() , why are they different?

Tags: python, image

Quick question about displaying an image with Python, difference between

```
im = Image.fromarray(noisyImage)
im.show(noisyImage)
```

I get this:

http://s30.postimg.org/xbkxly81t/other.png

Then when i use matplotlib i get this:

```
plt.imshow(noisyImage)
plt.show()
```

http://s30.postimg.org/64odx64ap/mtlibplt.png

please could someone explain why, when its the same image, just different method of display? really confused!! where does the colour even come from on the matplotlib?

Also whats all the noise at the top of the first image? if i do not attempt to change the image it is fine. thanks

thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems like you are plotting with a 'jet' colormap. Try: `plt.imshow(noisyImage , cmap="gray"`) And check that cols and rows are in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL's `show` is a convenience function which uses `os.system` to call some OS-dependent image viewer on your machine.

You can find out what command is being used to show the image 
by doing this:

```
In [37]: import ImageShow

In [38]: [viewer.get_command_ex('file')[0] for viewer in ImageShow._viewers]
Out[38]: ['display']
```

So on my Unix machine, PIL's `show` is using imagemagick's `display` program.

Matplotlib's `plt.show` function uses a [GUI backend](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements) such as `tk`, `gtk`, `pyqt` or `wxpython` to draw the plot.

Comment: Thanks for that! Makes things a little clearer. Although sometimes I get just random noise or python crashes. see here : http://s11.postimg.org/5tk6d1m2r/Poisson_Noise3.jpg so dont know why that is. But many thanks for the explanation as I was unsure of which would be best to use or if one displayed image was incorrect. seems they are both 'correct' just displayed in different ways.